# rosjava for javafx no maven (Kinetic)

Tags: java, ros-kinetic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a research project and have been tasked with creating a gui app in java/javafx that will connect to the lab robot (ros master) over the network. We want to be able to have a publisher and subscriber running in the app. We will be subscribing to a topic for image messages and will be publishing to a topic for custom messages to provide steering information.

I have not been able to get maven integrated into my javafx project on IntelliJ Idea and am thinking that I should just use the source repository and use jars and the files I need.

Does anyone know if it is possible for me to use ros messages without using maven or if I have to use maven can someone point me towards how to do it, i have been searching online for a solution but haven't found one.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301036/rosjava-for-javafx-no-maven-(kinetic)/) by [pulkitgupta1217](https://answers.ros.org/users/37076/pulkitgupta1217/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @pulkitgupta1217,

I'd use maven to download the artifacts directly.
In the repositories section of the `pom` file, add the following:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>rosjava_mvn</id>
        <name>Public Rosjava repository</name>
        <url>https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

That will point to `rosjava_mvn_repo`. Then, in the `dependencies` section, add the dependencies you need, e.g.:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ros.rosjava_core</groupId>
        <artifactId>rosjava</artifactId>
        <version>[0.3, 0.4)</version>
    </dependency>
```

This can include any message artifact you need.
Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2018-08-23**:
Did that work for you @pulkitgupta1217?

**Comment by [pulkitgupta1217](https://answers.ros.org/users/37076/pulkitgupta1217/) on 2018-08-23**:
yes, I was able to add the rosjava packages to a new maven project and migrate my code over, I am still unsure as to how i would integrate with a javafx application as it appears that the nodes much be launched from a main method but with a javafx application class and controller class, I am unsure.